# jerseyClient : JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, multipart, multipartentity

am working on jerseyClient 2,19 and trying to post a MultiPart Object and get the following error :

> Error :javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])

here ist my code :

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        WebTarget service = client.target("http://lap-020:7080/dima/api");

        MultiPart multiPartEntity = new MultiPart()
        .bodyPart(new BodyPart().entity("hello"))
        .bodyPart(new BodyPart().entity(new TimeInterval()));



    Response response = service.path("/orderPost").request().post(Entity.entity(multiPartEntity,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

what is the meaning of this error ?
My TimeInterval Object has the @XmlRootElement and @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)

Please Help!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Entity.entity(multiPartEntity,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`?

Comment: I read in the jersey doc and this is how to send and MultiPart Object  as JSON

Comment: Please link to that because it definitely is not. Also, what do you mean by _MultiPart Object as JSON_?

Comment: You seem to only want the second body part to be JSON. Then that's where you should set your content-type.

Comment: its work! just need to write it so: multiPartEntity.bodyPart(new BodyPart(location, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

Comment: @simplo, please consider posting the right answer (as an answer, not a comment) and, after that, accept it.